# How to parse String with Javascript looks like object

Tags: jquery, json, salesforce

I am getting a string like this.
I did type of and I get it as **string**.
String is pretty large so I am posting a part of it.

```
[System.SelectOption[value="account__c", label="Account", disabled="false"], System.SelectOption[value="account_owner__c", label="Account Owner", disabled="false"], System.SelectOption[value="accountname__c", label="Business Name", disabled="false"]]
```

What I need is a Json or an array of it. Please HELP.

Comment: Is this the string representation of a select element?

Comment: Amazed....Yes exactly....

Comment: How did you end up with this thing in the first place? can we see some code?

Comment: I can just help you with this string....It is a part of project...

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?
This code essentially converts the string to an array of key-value pairs.

JSFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/Dap6C/2/

```
var x = '[System.SelectOption[value="account__c", label="Account", disabled="false"], System.SelectOption[value="account_owner__c", label="Account Owner", disabled="false"], System.SelectOption[value="accountname__c", label="Business Name", disabled="false"]]';

x = x.substring(0, x.length - 1).substring(1, x.length).replace(/System.SelectOption/g,"");
var xp = x.substring(0, x.length - 1).substring(1, x.length).replace(/, /g,",");
var y = xp.split('],[');

var mainarray = [];
for(var i=0;i<y.length;i++){
 var z = y[i].split(',');
    var elements = [];
    for(var j=0;j<z.length;j++){
        var m = z[j] ;
        m =m.split('=');
        elements[m[0]] = m[1];
    }
    mainarray.push(elements);
}

var samplelement = mainarray[0];
document.write("<b>Sample output saved as key-value pairs = </b><br/>"+ "<b>value is </b> " + samplelement.value +  "<b>and label is </b> "+ samplelement.label + ' ');
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer....But I said that my string is huge....So I will be looking for something else....Still thanks a lot for the answer...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old and I'm guessing you've solved your issue but I've just had to do something similar and given this HTML and jQuery (just because):

```
<p><strong>Raw SF SelectOption data:</strong></p>
<div id="sfData"></div>
<p><strong>SF data converted to string with an array of objects using Regex:</strong></p>
<div id="sfDataToStr"></div>
<p><strong>SF data converted to proper array of Objects:</strong></p>
<div id="strToObj"></div>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
var sfData = 
    '[System.SelectOption[value="-- None --", label="-- None --", disabled="false"],' + 
    ' System.SelectOption[value="Special 1", label="Special 1", disabled="false"],' + 
    ' System.SelectOption[value="Special 2", label="Special 2", disabled="false"],' + 
    ' System.SelectOption[value="Special 3", label="Special 3", disabled="false"]]';
$(function(){
    $("#sfData").
        append(sfData).
        prepend($("<p></p>", {
            "text": "TYPE: " + typeof sfData}));
    var sfDataToStr = sfData.
        replace(/System.SelectOption\[(\w+)=/g, "{\"$1\":").
        replace(/\],\s?/g, "},").
        replace(/\",\s?(\w+)=/g, "\",\"$1\":").
        replace(/\]\]/g, "}]");
    $("#sfDataToStr").
        append(sfDataToStr).
        prepend($("<p></p>", {
            "text": "TYPE: " + typeof sfDataToStr}));
    var strToObj = JSON.parse(sfDataToStr);
    $("#strToObj").
        append(JSON.stringify(strToObj)).
        prepend($("<p></p>", {
            "text": "TYPE: " + typeof strToObj}));
});
```

I managed to get the data in a form that I was happy using.

I'm guessing that you're echoing an array of SalesForce SelectOption Objects and wanting to use them in JavaScript? I'm not sure if there is a native way for SalesForce to echo out proper JSON but this method worked for my purposes... hope it helps.

Working JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/02668Ld4/